# How to use the word "rave"

Tags: meaning, verbs, ambiguity

I am a little confused about how to use **rave**, because sometimes it means a bad thing like:

> A madman cried (raved) loudly.

Yesterday, my friend recommended me a movie by saying:

> My people raved about it, you'd better see it.

According to his expression, I guess it means a good movie.

Comment: Maybe you need to get used to people complementing you with statements like "That makes you so badass", "That's wicked sinful" or "There's an evil I like about you".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is **not on-topic** unless you show your research in the post. Please include the [research](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you've done. **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Sorry, feel free to delete my answer or the whole question. I should have looked at the FAQ.

Comment: @Mσᶎ It's OK. We are just trying to guide new users. Happy new year.

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Answer (score 3):

[Dictionary.com says:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rave)

> **Rave**: verb (used without object), raved, raving.
>
> 1. to talk wildly, as in delirium.
> 2. to talk or write with extravagant enthusiasm:
>
>    *She raved about her trip to Europe.*

While [Merriam-Webster give a slightly different second meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rave):

> : to talk or write about someone or something in an excited or enthusiastic way
>
> : to talk loudly in an angry or wild way

So yes, there are two meanings and you need to rely on context. In this case "raved" followed by "you have to see it" generally means the positive meaning.

But if your friend is prone to teasing you, or sarcasm, even that could mean "... because I hated it and you should be made to suffer like I did". A populist politician raved..." could have either meaning depending on whether the speaker agrees with the politician or disagrees.

As a side note "recommended me a movie" is [a common but arguable construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285590/recommend-me-vs-recommend-to-me).

Comment: The key point is the meaning could be completely different (agree, disagree). Not Easy.

Comment: @Max I don't know how anyone learns this language if they don't start as a baby.  Any**one**, **they**, **a** baby.  See what I mean?

Comment: @Max They're really not that different.They both indicate extreme enthusiasm. If that's appropriate, then it's good. If that's inappropriate, then it's bad. It is always the job of a person who uses language to ensure he provides enough clues to resolve any ambiguities for their reader/listener. In your examples, we have an abundance of clues -- the word "madman" (clearly bad), the phrase "you'd better see it" (clearly good).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz awesome answer